# UIAlertview and Segue pushing information

Tags: ios, objective-c

So the user needs to enter something into the UITextField from the UIAlertView. And then by clicking the oke button, he'll get to the next view with the information.

But i seem to be stuck?

I have this:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        UIStoryboardSegue *segue = [[UIStoryboardSegue alloc]  init];

        AddViewController *add = [segue destinationViewController];

        UITextField *textfield =  [alertView textFieldAtIndex: 0];

        [add set_aantalDice:textfield.text.intValue];

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addSegue" sender:self];

    }else{
        NSLog(@"Cancel");
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. How can i get the information trough with segue and an UIAlertView? I've been trying for like 3 hours now..

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Jonathan gave you a large explanation of all other things you did wrong, the problem is much smaller. Your `UIAlertView` is dismissed and when segue happens the data is not there anymore. The `AddViewController` you created yourself is only a local variable and is not used in the segue at all, so the properties you set are discarded.

**If you want to use a segue, you need to do it Apple's way.** This means providing the data by overriding `prepareForSegue` method.

So what you need to do is:

1. Create a property in the current view controller, that will store the string in `UITextField` on `UIAlertView`.

   ```
   @property (nonatomic) NSInteger aantalDice;
   ```
2. Store the text in `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` with the following code (all other code should be removed):

   ```
   UITextField *textfield = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];

   [self setAantalDice:textfield.text.intValue];

   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addSegue" sender:self];
   ```
3. Implement `prepareForSegue:` method.

   ```
   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
   {
       if ([segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"addSegue"])
       {
           AddViewController * addViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

           [addViewController set_aantalDice:self.aantalDice];
       }
   }
   ```

**The data should now be in the `AddViewController`.**

This is because, because `performSegueWithIdentifier` method handles the `UIViewController` creation itself, so you do not have to instantiate new view controller yourself.

Comment: Thanks! So basically i misunderstood it. And performSegueWithIdentifier, is always called when using [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addSegue" sender:self];

Comment: Yes, `prepareForSegue` is always called, when you call `performSegueWithIdentifier`, so do not worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manually create a segue in code you should use the following UIStoryboardSegue factory method.

```
segueWithIdentifier:source:destination:performHandler:
```

Method Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIStoryboardSegue/segueWithIdentifier:source:destination:performHandler:

I find generic segues easier to manage using Interface Builder. All you need to do is create a manual segue from ViewController A to ViewController B by pressing control+drag on ViewController A to ViewController B. Then, select the type (e.g. Push, Modal) and give the segue an identifier.

Next, remove the code below from the UIAlertView Delegate method:

```
UIStoryboardSegue *segue = [[UIStoryboardSegue alloc]  init];

AddViewController *add = [segue destinationViewController];

UITextField *textfield =  [alertView textFieldAtIndex: 0];

[add set_aantalDice:textfield.text.intValue];
```

Then, implement the method `prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` in ViewController A.

In the definition of the aforementioned method place the following code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"addSegue"])
    {
        AddViewController * addViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        UITextField * textfield =  [alertView textFieldAtIndex: 0];

        [addViewController set_aantalDice:textfield.text.intValue];
    }
}
```

**Optional:**

Instead of checking if the buttonIndex == 1 you could also check if the button's title is == @"Okay".

E.g.

```
if ([[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] isEqualToString:@"Okay"])
{
    // Do something...
}
```

**Explanation:**

In the code that you have now you are allocating an instance of UIStoryBoardSegue without the proper information needed to perform the segue (e.g. Identifier, Source View Controller, and Destination View Controller). When you attempt to access the destination ViewController using [segue destinationViewController] the value will return nil because the instance of the segue does not have a destination. When you attempt to perform the segue with the identifier @"addSegue" nothing will happen because the segue that you have instantiated has no identifier.

I recommend reading about segues here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html

And here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH8-SW4

Hopefully this helps.